# Not able to install new softwares (e.g. Fabric, Virtualenvwrapper)

Tags: python, terminal, pip

I'm unable to install new tools like Fabric and Virtualenvwrapper.  Any suggestions?  I was having the same issue before I started using the virtualenv delivery -- tried that as a solution.  Here's the error that I got when trying to install Fabric:

```
^C(delivery) Bryans-MacBook-Pro:skyway bryanaltman$ 
(delivery) Bryans-MacBook-Pro:skyway bryanaltman$ pip install fabric
Collecting fabric
  Using cached Fabric-1.13.1-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting paramiko<3.0,>=1.10 (from fabric)
  Using cached paramiko-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from paramiko<3.0,>=1.10->fabric)
Collecting cryptography>=1.1 (from paramiko<3.0,>=1.10->fabric)
  Using cached cryptography-1.7.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_10_intel.whl
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.4.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko<3.0,>=1.10->fabric)
Collecting setuptools>=11.3 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko<3.0,>=1.10->fabric)
  Using cached setuptools-33.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko<3.0,>=1.10->fabric)
Collecting idna>=2.0 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko<3.0,>=1.10->fabric)
  Using cached idna-2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipaddress (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko<3.0,>=1.10->fabric)
  Using cached ipaddress-1.0.18-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting enum34 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko<3.0,>=1.10->fabric)
  Using cached enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->cryptography>=1.1->paramiko<3.0,>=1.10->fabric)
Installing collected packages: setuptools, idna, ipaddress, enum34, cryptography, paramiko, fabric
  Found existing installation: setuptools 1.1.6
    Uninstalling setuptools-1.1.6:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/var/folders/0j/zlx16g516yn1_228k12dbrl00000gn/T/pip-KdYiO4-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0j/zlx16g516yn1_228k12dbrl00000gn/T/pip-KdYiO4-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/var/folders/0j/zlx16g516yn1_228k12dbrl00000gn/T/pip-KdYiO4-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0j/zlx16g516yn1_228k12dbrl00000gn/T/pip-KdYiO4-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/var/folders/0j/zlx16g516yn1_228k12dbrl00000gn/T/pip-KdYiO4-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0j/zlx16g516yn1_228k12dbrl00000gn/T/pip-KdYiO4-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/var/folders/0j/zlx16g516yn1_228k12dbrl00000gn/T/pip-KdYiO4-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0j/zlx16g516yn1_228k12dbrl00000gn/T/pip-KdYiO4-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/var/folders/0j/zlx16g516yn1_228k12dbrl00000gn/T/pip-KdYiO4-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0j/zlx16g516yn1_228k12dbrl00000gn/T/pip-KdYiO4-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
(delivery) Bryans-MacBook-Pro:skyway bryanaltman$
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your virtualenv might be corrupted.  The easiest thing is to delete the following files and then recreate it.  You’ll also want to make sure that you have the latest python 2.7 installed using brew.  You’ll want to verify that you have checked in all your work so far in case you have any files of your own located in the `bin`, `lib` or `include` directories.

```
brew install python
cd /path/to/skyway
deactivate # if you are already in a virtualenv session
if [ -f './Python' ] ; then rm -f ./Python ; fi
rm -r bin lib include
virtualenv . -p /usr/local/bin/python
. bin/activate
pip install fabric
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Still having the same error though :/